# Scaling a font on a multilined UIButton depending on a device size

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit, interface-builder

Current setup:

I have a *multilined* `UIButton` which is added to its superview (an ordinary `UIView`). Button's width is 90% of its superview. So when its superview's size changes, label's width changes accordingly due to `Autolayout` constraints.

Next, inside of viewDidLoad method I did this:

```
  //Line break mode and Font size ( are set in Interface Builder
  myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
  myButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 15.0
  myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
```

So now, when I have long text, on iPhone devices I get something like this: [image: iPhone look]

which is exactly what I want.  But of course, this looks different on iPad devices. For example, this is on iPad Pro 9.7":

[image: iPad Pro look]

And as it can be see, everything looks small and bad.

What I have tried:

I tried to set maximum font size (which will be used on iPad devices), in combination with `minimumScaleFactore = 15`. So I've set font size to 25 and now everything looks more acceptable on both iPad and iPhone, but still, on the iPhone devices, text is a bit bigger than I need because of how minimumScaleFactor works.

What would be a way to solve this?

I am more into getting something like this (to get similar look on all iPad and iPhone devices):

[image: desired iPad look]

Comment: So basically, I am looking a way to setup all this in some way, ideally through IB, or if not possible, through the code, but I am trying to avoid to set font based on a detected device programmatically. I mean nothing bad with that, but I was wondering is there something more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use size classes to specify the font on your button/label in IB. Just press the little + sign to the left of the font property:

[image: Just press the little + sign to the left of the font property]

Comment: This looks promising... How I haven't noticed this :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I will award the bounty to this answer as soon as possible (I have to wait 4 more hours or so, due to how system works)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot vary the font for the button in interface builder based on the size class; however you can remove entire controls based on the size class.  Choose the attributes inspector (Option+command+4) with your button selected.  Scroll all the way to the bottom and you will see a check box for installed with a tiny plus button on the left.  If you click the plus you can now add variations of size classes to uninstall this control.  Specifically uninstall it for Regular Width Regular Height (which is iPad in non split screen).  Now make a second button with your iPad attributes and install it ONLY for Regular Width Regular Height.  You now have two different buttons: 1) for iPad in no split screen and one for everything else, no code needed.  You can set them to invoke the same IBAction.  See this [link for more](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html).

Comment: `Sadly you cannot vary the font for the button in interface builder based on the size class`: That is not true. See my answer.

Comment: Josh, what you have proposed works as well, so you have my upvote, But Mihai's answer is more elegant solution in this case. Still, your first sentence seems to be misleading so you may want to edit your answer to be more useful for future readers.