# How to declare different font sizes for same size class in adaptive auto layout in xcode?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

Adaptive Auto layout supports size class specific font size adjustments but what if I want to provide different font size for iphone 4/4s, 5/5s, 6/6s and 7/7s? all are compact-regular size class.

Comment: I just asked something similar here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41676962/3402095. I am currently playing with Traits to see if that could solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work with adaptive layout. Apple thinks, you should use the same font size for these different devices if they have the same size class.

You might have to get the screen size and change the font size according to that.

Comment: So, this is not a great addition then, It doesn't solve the problem till root, finally developer ends up adjusting at runtime.

Comment: Depends. Most of the times I'm completely fine with the solution Apple provided. Apple builds its stuff for 80% of the users/developers. You might be one of the missing 20% in this case.

Comment: 1. So can I've the alternate story boards for such cases? or 2. changing at runtime which is better?

Comment: Yes. You still would have to decide which storyboard should be used depending on the screen size.

Comment: I pick multiple story boards option against run time changes, and will make the right decision which story board to use. This is android-way of doing stuff where OS automatically detects alternate layout based on best match available. Can I go ahead like this?

Comment: You still need a runtime check/decision which storyboard should be used.

Comment: Well I think that is unavoidable by the architecture what iOS supports, someone should make a decision either at build time or at runtime. Build time would be great but by architecture not possible, so left over is runtime decision. I think should be fine right?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion dasdom